# Permutation Group as quotient of Free Group

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

I could use some help with the following question:

Let $S_{n}$
  be the permutation group of $\left\{ 1,...,n\right\}$
 , what is the minimal $k\in\mathbb{N}$
  such that $S_{n}$
  is a quotient of the free group $F_{k}$
  (free group with k
  generators).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Alternatively, what is the size of the smallest set of generators of $S_n$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly, $k>1$ (except for which small values of $n$?).
Can you see how $S_n=\langle(1\, 2),(1\,2\,\ldots\,n)\rangle$ and hence $k\le 2$?

Comment: I wasn't familiar with that set of generators for $S_{n}$ but it certainly clarifies it :)
Obviously for n=1,2 it would be k=1 and otherwise 2.
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Actually, when $n=1$, you can use the free group on $0$ generators...